# toggleClass unique background

Tags: jquery, css, addclass, removeclass, toggleclass

I have search and tried this, please help!
So here is what i have working perfectly so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/ANDXJ/88/

```
$('.product').hide();

$('#nav a').click(function(){
    var idvar = this.id;
    var selected_item = $('#product_'+idvar);                  
    var visible_item = $('.product:visible'); 

    if( visible_item.length > 0 && selected_item.attr('id') !== visible_item.attr('id') ){
        visible_item.slideUp(function(){ selected_item.slideToggle() }); 
    }else{
        selected_item.slideToggle(); 
    }

    return false;
});
```

I'm able to toggle this perfectly, except I want the background of the div (in this case "more-info") to stay blue when it's "active". Currently i'm using a pseudo class for a sample of kinda what I want it to do, but ultimately i want to click the "more-info", the text drops down, and the background stays blue until i click another box (or the same box); then it looses the blue...

One caveat is that i cannot use "siblings" because obviously these nav items aren't in a list... or any particular order.

Any help GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ANDXJ/91/ here you go, just keep using class flags to handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ANDXJ/93/

**CSS:**

edit this line:

```
.more-info:active, .more-info.active {
```

**MODIFIED and simplified HTML** (`You cannot have duplicate ID elements!`) :

```
<div class="nav">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="more-info"></div>
        </a>
</div>
<div  class="twelve columns product">  
      <p>test</p>
</div>

<div class="nav">
         <a href="#">
            <div class="more-info"></div>
        </a>
</div>
<div class="twelve columns product">  
    <p>testies</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

    $('.product').hide();

    $('.nav').click(function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $that = $(this),
            $info = $that.find('.more-info'),
            $prod = $that.next('.product');
        $('.more-info').removeClass('active');        
        return $prod.is(':visible')?
        /* YES: */ [ $prod.slideUp(), $info.removeClass('active') ] :
        /* NO:  */ [ $('.product').slideUp(),  $prod.slideDown(), $info.addClass('active') ] ;
    });

});
```